# In mongo, can we create a database in a replica set, which will be in Primary only and won't sync to secondary instance

Tags: mongodb

Like, I have 3 member replica set and I want to create a database in primary and it should not be copied to secondary.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. What if Primary goes down and secondary server becomes Primary and second database does not exists.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of replica sets is exactly what it says - replication. You can not have a special database database in a replica set that does not get replicated.

What if you primary goes down? Then your next primary wont have this special database, but your application will still expect it to be there.

It sounds like you've got more of a design issue than anything. You need to ask yourself why you need a special database that cant be replicated. Are you sure it cant? Maybe it should just be on a separate replica set? Because certainly what you are planning is not the right approach.